# Some internals of Django auth middleware

Tags: python, django

In the django.contrib.auth middleware
I see the code:

```
class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'session'), "requires session middleware"
        request.__class__.user = LazyUser()
        return None
```

Please avdise me why such a form 
    request._ *class* _.user = LazyUser()
used? 
Why not just
    request.user = LazyUser()
?

I know what _ *class* _ attribute means, but as I undersand direct assignment to instance variable will be better. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LazyUser` is descriptor-class. According to [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) it can be only class attribute not instance one:

> For instance, `a.x` has a lookup chain starting with `a.__dict__['x']`, then `type(a).__dict__['x']`, and continuing through the base classes of `type(a)` excluding metaclasses.

Comment: Oh, yes!

Sometime I really miss 'pythonic' way of thinking :)

Java stereotypes are still there...

Answer (score -1):

This is going to affect how `request`s are created.  All such instances will have their `user` attribute as that particular `LazuUser` without the need to make that change after each individual `request` is instantiated.